# Can we set values to interface methods from class A and get values from class B in java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, javac

I have a Events interface contains two methods

```
Interface Events{
      public Event save(Event event);
      public search(int a, int b);
}
class A implements Events(){
      implementing methos and set values;
}
class B implements Events{
Getting values from already set through class A to ClassB
}
```

Is it possible, if it is please show me one simple example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: public Interface Events{ Event save(Event event); String search(String a, String b);}

Comment: The static method of interface can set value from class A and get value from class B. But none static methods you can not do such thing.

Comment: Normally, you get values from an object, not a class, unless you're talking about static fields.  You'll need to start with a program that creates objects from both classes, then retrieves values from one object and stores them in the other.